# Funeral vs. burial

Tags: single-word-request, expression

In the forum for the web app [webtrees](https://webtrees.net), there were [differing opinions](https://www.webtrees.net/index.php/en/forum/help-for-release-2-1-x/37924-funeral-gedcom-tag#100444) on this topic.  I don't speak German, but [Deepl](https://DeepL.com) suggests both *Beerdigung* and *Begräbnis* can be translated as either "burial" or "funeral."

For automated localization of the app are there any two distinct words (or phrases) X & Y that would be sufficiently unambiguous for
funeral → X
burial  → Y
?

It's a genealogical app which tries to comply with a [communication standard](https://www.familysearch.org/en/GEDCOM/gedcom-the-standard-file-format-for-family-history).  But it allows users to select a language, and the text shown to users need a discrete equivalence to the events defined in the spec.  For this area, there are currently two: burial & cremation.  But adding "funeral" has been requested for the next version.

Comment: What's the difference between funeral and burial? If they are synonym, how could a translation to two synonyms be unambiguous?

Comment: They are not synonyms!  They are usually in different places, and sometimes they are on different days. … https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/funeral#English … https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burial#English

Comment: I always considered them to mean the same. From the two links you give, I also don't quite see what's the difference of the two English words - but I'm no English native speaker. Can you explain to me?

Comment: In German there are also many more words around this topic... like Trauerfeier and Beisetzung... so you really have to explain what is the difference in meaning you want to capture. Some sites do seem to make a distinction but they not seem to be unanimously agree on a clear distinction between burial and funeral - yet with a tendency of the first meaning to put the dead body to Earth (which form?), and the latter more the memorial service or description of the whole process?

Comment: @planetmaker from the definitions in wiktionary it's clear: Funeral is the service where they honour the person, possibly with an open casket and for christians likely held in a church or chapel. The burial is the act of burying and putting the casket into the ground.

Comment: Perhaps language follows culture here: in english-speaking countries it is custom to have a celebration (-> funeral) and an interment (->burial) as two distinct occasions. In german-speaking countries this is generally not the case, these two are one celebration and hence "Begräbnis" and "Beerdigung" (also "Beisetzung", as @planetmaker mentioned) are synonyms. Language cannot be used without the cultural background it emerged out of. (There is no german word for "fairness" and there is no english word for "Fleiß".)

Comment: Please mention the difference between _funderal_ and _burial_ in your question, to make it easier for future readers to understand the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- burial (=act of putting the casket to the ground) is usually translated as "Beisetzung"
- funeral (=act of a memorial service, e.g. held in church) is usually translated as "Trauerfeier".

The above two words are commonly used in small texts in the local newspaper to make the distinction and e.g. invite everyone to the funeral, but also explicitly mention that the burial will take place later with only the family being around (and implicitly others unwelcome).

As often this can be one process, the words "Begräbnis" or "Beerdigung" are used as well, though they imply that the body or casket is put into Earth (so not so fitting for a cremation), so have a closer resemblence to "Beisetzung".

Answer (score 3):

This is both a cultural and language question. In German-speaking countries, he ceremony and the act of burying the corpse traditionally tended to be the same thing - thus, *Begräbnis*, *Beerdigung* (while literally noting the burial of the remains of the deceased) somewhat implicitly include the ceremony as well. In cases where there is no literal act of burying the corpse into the ground (like when the body has been cremated or *burial at sea* [1]) you can also use *Bestattung* or *Beisetzung*, which don't target **the ground** specifically, but denote the general act of resting the bodily remains.

A term that targets the *ceremony* as explicit part of the *Beerdigung* would be *Trauerfeier* or more traditionally "Leich" in dialect, in some regions even the somewhat creepy *Leichenschmaus* (denoting what English would call *funeral meal* or *the wake*). Traditionally, the latter two are not held in public, but with a number of selected guests from family and friends, while *Trauerfeier* is more public.

[1] Which is somewhat of an inconsistent term even in English